# Relay export of multiple connectionDefinitions used in different schemas

Tags: javascript, import, graphql, relay

I´m using GraphQL and `graphql-relay` in a project where I have several connection definitions used in different types and some of the connection definitions are repeated around types.

My first approach for handling connection definition was:

```
   import { connectionDefinitions } from 'graphql-relay';

   import { CustomerType } from './Customer/types';

   const { connectionType: CustomerConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: CustomerType });
```

That was placed in different GraphQL types every time I needed that connection.

After some issues I found out that I cannot define more than once a connection definition in the whole project, causing an `Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named CustomerType`.

So, I decided to build a central place to define all the connect definitions and to export it to all GraphQL types that needs it in a file named `relaydefs.js`:

```
import { connectionDefinitions } from 'graphql-relay';

import { CustomerType } from './Customer/types';
import { ItemType } from './Item/types';
import { StockType } from './Stock/types';
import { PriceListType } from './PriceItem/types';

export const { connectionType: CustomerConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: CustomerType });
export const { connectionType: ItemConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: ItemType });
export const { connectionType: StockConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: StockType });
export const { connectionType: PriceListConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: PriceListType });
```

And on every module issuing a:

```
import { CustomerConnectionType } from './relaydefs';
```

Well, the import is not working, as only the first item is being imported (all others retrieves `undefined`).

I´m sure this is a pure javascript import problem, not relay or GraphQL, but I need help to:

a) How to properly import each define connection type ?

b) Is this a good approach in a case where I have a connection type used in multiple types ? Any better solution ?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this question? I am also facing a similar issue where I want to use Connections of a particular nodeType in different schemas and ObjectTypes but getting the same error that you posted.

Comment: No. I had to re-architecture the whole relay structure putting each connectionDefinitoin on a single file used by a single type.

Comment: Isn't that restrictive? For example, if I have PersonType, I want to query and paginate on persons (with nodeType as PersonType). Also, persons might be a field in CompanyType which I also want to use connections on to paginate persons. Why can't I do that referencing the connection with same NodeType in two places?